# How to add HTML code inside a JS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to include a HTML which adds a preview pane inside a JavaScript function, something like this :

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="height: 70%; border: 1px solid #000; overflow: auto;">
        <div style="background: #ddd; height: 1000px;">master</div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 30%; border: 1px solid; #000; overflow: auto;">
        <div style="background: #ddd; height: 1000px;">detail</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And the question is.......

Comment: Take HTML in string and give that source to preview pane.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. use some template engine like:

   - mustaches https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/
   - angular https://angularjs.org/
2. write the code as text inside a var and then append it to them dom. (see `document.write()`)

Answer (score 0):

just use quotes around html like

```
var a = 'some string';
```

just you will have to have all hmtl in 1 line or add line by line to var.

Or use ES5 and just make like this:

```
let a = `any
string
with new lines`;
```

Or

Use jsx with ReactJs for html inside js! It's awesome :-) Last time i wrote html outside js was like 2 years ago..
https://facebook.github.io/react/

great place to start learning:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLb0IAmt7-GS1cbw4qonlQztYV1TAW0sCr

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you are asking... 
Do you want to add HTML dynamically via JavaScript? 
This is a way to do it with jQuery:

```
var html = '<div id="whatever"></div>';
$("body").prepend(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write html markup in javascript you can move towards React JS this is very power full engine for writing html markup in javascript it provides lot of others things.